# Hiding multiple web services behind one?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

There is a system with a rather big amount of different small services.
The idea is to hide them behind one, which is going to be an entry point to the system.
Is that considered a good practice?
Are there any common approaches/solutions for such case in asp.net core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called an [API Gateway pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html).

> API gateway is the single entry point for all clients. The API gateway handles requests in one of two ways. Some requests are simply proxied/routed to the appropriate service. It handles other requests by fanning out to multiple services.

[image]

As the starting point, you may look into [Proxy Middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy) for ASP.NET Core.